# How to display a new control through trigger in WPF

Tags: wpf

Now I got a `Grid` and I'm trying to display a control, lets say a `StackPanel` in the grid to cover the origin content when the mouse enters. I put the `StackPanel` in the first row, made its ZIndex=10(greater than Grid) and property `Visibility` binding to the Grid's `IsMouseOver` property. This trick just has one defect: the `StackPanel` will influence the grid's layout. For example, if the `StackPanel`'s width is up to 500 and the original Grid only 100, the Grid expands quietly annoyingly. Here is the XAML snippet

```
 <Grid x:Name="FileControlGrid">
    !--The StackPanel to display when mouse enters--!
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ZIndex="10" Grid.Row="0" 
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=FileControlGrid, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource MouseoverToVisibilityCvt}}">
        <...>
    </StackPanel>
    !--Origin Content below, I need the stackpanel to cover the Image--!
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding FilePath, Converter={StaticResource FileiconCvt}}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5" Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Times New Roman" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="SemiBold"  MaxWidth="150" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="14"/>
</Grid>
```

I attempted using the `Trigger`, but instead of setting simple properties, I've no idea how to generate a grandly new control in triggers. Anyone can help?
[Images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34jEw.jpg)

Comment: If a control should cover another control, don't nest one in the other. Instead put them in the same parent

Comment: In fact, I just need the stackpanel to cover the Image. Problem is the stackpanel automatically changes the grid's width. I just put an Figure about the issue. Any good suggestions?@ErnodeWeerd

Comment: You could bind the width of the StackPanel to the width of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't understand the reason why you want to display the StackPanel in MouseOver but here is a simple solution that should work :

- Create two properties of Visibility ImageVisiable and StackPanelVisiable.
- Connect both properties to the Controls
- MouseEnter event Switch between them

Example :

Xaml Side :

```
<Grid x:Name="Mouse" MouseEnter="Mouse_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Mouse_MouseLeave">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--The StackPanel to display when mouse enters-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding StackPanelVisiable}"  Grid.Row="0">
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Origin Content below, I need the stackpanel to cover the Image-->
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/Superman.jpg"  Visibility="{Binding ImageVisiable}"  Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5" Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Times New Roman" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="SemiBold"  MaxWidth="150" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="14"/>
</Grid>
```

View Model :

```
private Visibility m_stackVisibility;
private Visibility m_imageVisibility;
public MainVM()
{
    m_stackVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    m_imageVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

}
public Visibility StackPanelVisiable
{
    get { return m_stackVisibility; }
    set { SetProperty(ref m_stackVisibility , value); }
}
public Visibility ImageVisiable
{
    get { return m_imageVisibility; }
    set { SetProperty(ref m_imageVisibility, value); }
}

    private void Mouse_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainVM)this.DataContext).StackPanelVisiable = Visibility.Hidden;
        ((MainVM)this.DataContext).ImageVisiable = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Mouse_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainVM)this.DataContext).ImageVisiable = Visibility.Hidden;
        ((MainVM)this.DataContext).StackPanelVisiable = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Hope it helped

Asaf